# How can I delete a message by message id with MailKit POP3 client?

Tags: email, pop3, mailkit

I want to use the MailKit `Pop3Client` to retrieve messages from a POP3 mailbox, and then delete these messages after processing. The retrieval code is something like:

```
Public Function GetMessages(Optional logPath As String = Nothing) As List(Of MimeMessage)

    Dim client As Pop3Client
    Dim messages = New List(Of MimeMessage)()

    Using client
        ConnectPop3(client)
        Dim count = client.GetMessageCount()
        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            Dim msg = client.GetMessage(i)
            messages.Add(msg)
        Next
    End Using

    Return messages

End Function
```

My problem here is in order to delete a message in another message, I need an index, but that is long gone once I exit `GetMessages`. All I have is the info available on a `MimeMessage` object, but that has no index property, only `MessageId`, but in my Delete method, I would have to read all mails again, in order to look up an index value.

Now `Pop3Client` has a `GetMessageUid(int index)` method, which returns a mysterious string (looks like int) value with no apparent relation at all to the Mime MessageID, but it seems this is all I have. Then I have to store the MailKit Uid with each message, making my retrieval code something like this, using a dictionary to store uid-message pairs:

```
Public Function GetMessages(Optional delete As Boolean = False, Optional logPath As String = Nothing) As List(Of MimeMessage)

    Dim client As Pop3Client
    Dim messages = New Dictionary(Of String, MimeMessage)

    Using client
        ConnectPop3(client)
        Dim count = client.GetMessageCount()
        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            Dim msg = client.GetMessage(i)
            Dim u = client.GetMessageUid(i)
            messages.Add(u, msg)
        Next
        client.Disconnect(True)
    End Using

    Return messages

End Function
```

I am really hoping I'm missing something here and what should be a really simple process is indeed simple, but I can't find anything else on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message UID is the only way to track a message between connections.

The index for a message can change as other messages are deleted.

Your options are:

- Delete messages as you're downloading them.
- Save the UID so you can come back and delete specific messages later.

It may make more sense if you skim through the [POP3 RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt).

Comment: Thanks. I had a, mistaken, impression that something like `GetMessageUid`, especially with a shiny client like MailKit, would return the `message-id` value for the message, but I'm heading back to the drawing board.

Comment: But how do you delete a message by MessageID? `POP3.DeleteMessage()` only take index as argument. `folder.AddFlags` is only for imap, right?

Comment: Maybe the only way is to iterate all messages and compare MessageID and the delete with the index, no shortcut, right?